# Using flufl.bounce with poplib/email modules

Tags: python, email, python-2.7

I am trying to use flufl.bounce to scan emails downloaded with poplib and detect bounced e-mail addresses. So far, what I'm getting is a lot of empty sets. Here is some sample code:

```
import getpass, poplib, email
from flufl.bounce import scan_message


user = 'redacted@redacted.com'
mail = poplib.POP3_SSL('redacted.redacted.com', '995')
mail.user(user)
mail.pass_('redacted')

num_messages = len(mail.list()[1])

for i in range(num_messages):
    for msg in mail.retr(i+1)[1]:
        msg = email.message_from_string(msg)        
        bounce = scan_message(msg)
        print bounce
mail.quit()
```

And `print bounce` is giving me an empty set:

```
set([])
```

There are various types of bounce messages in this mailbox, and I can even select one with mail.retr that I know is a bounce message, but when I feed it into `scan_message`, I still get an empty set back. What am I doing wrong? The [flufl.bounce docs](http://pythonhosted.org/flufl.bounce/docs/using.html) don't seem to be very helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.`msg` is a list of the elements of the e-mail. So, instead of iterating through `mail.retr(i+1)[1]`, I had to join it together with \n before feeding it into `email.message_from_string()` which gave me a proper message that `scan_message` could use. Here's the working code

```
import getpass, poplib, email
from flufl.bounce import scan_message

user = 'redacted@redacted.com'
mail = poplib.POP3_SSL('mail.redacted.com', '995')
mail.user(user)
mail.pass_('redacted')

num_messages = len(mail.list()[1])

for i in range(num_messages):
    x = mail.retr(i+1)[1]
    msg = email.message_from_string("\n".join(x))                
    bounce = scan_message(msg)
    print bounce
mail.quit()
```